# How to use two different custom signup forms with two different models with devise and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-routing

I have two different models professional and employer.  Both need a specific sign_up or registration page.  They have some things in common but many more that are not so single table.  I am also using devise.  Here are the models:

```
class Professional < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

validates_presence_of :name, :email, :phone_number, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :skills, 
   :experience, :languages, :software, :education, :pay_range, :bio
validates :phone_number, format: /\(?(\d{3})\)?[\W\D]?(\d{3})[\W\D]?(\d{4})/
validates :email, format: /\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b/

has_many :jobs
has_one :resume
has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable
has_many :contracts
has_many :employers, through: :contracts
has_one :user, :as => :rolable

end
```

and the other one:

```
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates_presence_of :name, :email, :phone_number, :address, :city, :state, :zip, 
      :office_type, :number_of_hygenists, :assisted?, 
      :software_type, :paperless?, :parking, :patients_per_day, :languages_required, 
      :about
  validates :phone_number, format: /\(?(\d{3})\)?[\W\D]?(\d{3})[\W\D]?(\d{4})/
  validates :email, format: /\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b/

  has_many :jobs
  has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable
  has_many :professionals, through: :contracts
  has_many :contracts
  has_one :user, :as => :rolable

 end
```

The problem is that when I try to make the view go to the signup of either signup view for either model it just goes though the devise controller.

Here is the root page:

```
   %h1 Staffolution
   %br
   %br
   %h2 This is the placeholder for the welcome/home page
   %br
   %br
   .container.c
     %p 
       For Employers
       %ul.nav
         %li 
           = link_to 'Sign In',  new_employer_session_path
         %li
           = link_to 'Sign Up',  new_employer_registration_path
     %p
       For Profesionals     
       %ul.nav
         %li 
           = link_to 'Sign In',  new_professional_session_path
         %li
           = link_to 'Sign Up',  new_professional_registration_path
```

Here is the routes.rb:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
   devise_for :professionals
   devise_for :employers

   mount JasmineRails::Engine => '/specs' if defined?(JasmineRails)

   root to: 'pages#home'

   resources :professionals 
   resources :employers
 end
```

Here is my rake routes: (sorry for the bad format)

```
                      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
    new_professional_session GET    /professionals/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        professional_session POST   /professionals/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_professional_session DELETE /professionals/sign_out(.:format)     devise/sessions#destroy
       professional_password POST   /professionals/password(.:format)     devise/passwords#create
   new_professional_password GET    /professionals/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_professional_password GET    /professionals/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /professionals/password(.:format)     devise/passwords#update
                             PUT    /professionals/password(.:format)     devise/passwords#update
 cancel_professional_registration GET /professionals/cancel(.:format) devise/registrations#cancel
   professional_registration POST   /professionals(.:format)   devise/registrations#create
  new_professional_registration GET    /professionals/sign_up(.:format)  devise/registrations#new
   edit_professional_registration GET    /professionals/edit(.:format)  devise/registrations#edit
                             PATCH  /professionals(.:format)  devise/registrations#update
                             PUT    /professionals(.:format)    devise/registrations#update
                             DELETE /professionals(.:format)  devise/registrations#destroy
        new_employer_session GET    /employers/sign_in(.:format)           devise/sessions#new
            employer_session POST   /employers/sign_in(.:format)           devise/sessions#create
    destroy_employer_session DELETE /employers/sign_out(.:format)  devise/sessions#destroy
           employer_password POST   /employers/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#create
       new_employer_password GET    /employers/password/new(.:format)      devise/passwords#new
      edit_employer_password GET    /employers/password/edit(.:format)     devise/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /employers/password(.:format)  devise/passwords#update
                             PUT    /employers/password(.:format)  devise/passwords#update
   cancel_employer_registration GET    /employers/cancel(.:format)   devise/registrations#cancel
       employer_registration POST   /employers(.:format)   devise/registrations#create
   new_employer_registration GET    /employers/sign_up(.:format)  devise/registrations#new
  edit_employer_registration GET    /employers/edit(.:format)    devise/registrations#edit
                             PATCH  /employers(.:format)   devise/registrations#update
                             PUT    /employers(.:format)       devise/registrations#update
                             DELETE /employers(.:format)          devise/registrations#destroy
               jasmine_rails        /specs                                 JasmineRails::Engine
                        root GET    /                                      pages#home
               professionals GET    /professionals(.:format)               professionals#index
                             POST   /professionals(.:format)               professionals#create
            new_professional GET    /professionals/new(.:format)           professionals#new
           edit_professional GET    /professionals/:id/edit(.:format)      professionals#edit
                professional GET    /professionals/:id(.:format)           professionals#show
                             PATCH  /professionals/:id(.:format)           professionals#update
                             PUT    /professionals/:id(.:format)           professionals#update
                             DELETE /professionals/:id(.:format)           professionals#destroy
                   employers GET    /employers(.:format)                   employers#index
                             POST   /employers(.:format)                   employers#create
                new_employer GET    /employers/new(.:format)               employers#new
               edit_employer GET    /employers/:id/edit(.:format)          employers#edit
                    employer GET    /employers/:id(.:format)               employers#show
                             PATCH  /employers/:id(.:format)               employers#update
                             PUT    /employers/:id(.:format)               employers#update
                             DELETE /employers/:id(.:format)               employers#destroy

   Routes for JasmineRails::Engine:
    root GET  /           jasmine_rails/spec_runner#index
```

Here are the controllers:

```
   class EmployersController < ApplicationController

     before_action :authenticate_employer!

     def index

     end

     def new
       @employer = Employer.new
     end  

     def edit
       @employer = current_employer
     end

     def update
       @employer = Employer.find(params[:id])
       @employer.update_attributes(employer_params)
       redirect_to employers_path 
     end

     def employer_params
       params.require(:employer).permit(:name, :phone_number, :address, 
         :office_type, :number_of_hygenists, :assisted?, :software_type, 
         :paperless?, :patients_per_day, :parking, :languages_required, 
         :about, :city, :state, :zip)
     end
```

and:

```
   class ProfessionalsController < ApplicationController

     before_action :authenticate_professional!

     def new
       @professional = Professional.new params[:professional]
       if @event.save!   
         redirect_to professional_index_path
       else
     end  

     def edit
       @professional = current_professional
     end

     def update
       @professional = Professional.find(params[:id])
       @professional.update_attributes(professional_params)
       redirect_to professional_path 
     end

     def employer_params
       params.require(:professional).permit(:name, :email, 
         :phone_number, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :skills, 
         :experience, :languages, :software, :education, 
         :pay_range, :bio)
     end
   end
```

Any help would be great I am kinda new and kinda not but mostly new to rails.

Comment: Depending on how different the attributes are for each professional and employer, why don't you have a flag in a user model for example that such as user_type and that can be populated with employer or professional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem does not seem clear to me. Although I am guessing you want to have custom controller for devise. You need to create a new controller like say registration controller and override the devise registration controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    #Insert Your Logic here
  end
end
```

Also you would have to add the below in the routes and add the paths as per your need.

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }, :path => "", :path_names => {:sign_out => "signout", :sign_up => "signup"}
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT :

You can also have different register actions for the different roles. You could define professional_user_register method for professional users and employee_register for employees. You could have to define these actions in the routes. See below samples

Routes

```
devise_scope :user do
    post "professional/register" =>"registrations#employee_register"
end

devise_scope :user do
    post "employee/register" =>"registrations#professional_user_register"
end
```

Registration Controller

```
def employee_register
  #Employee Register Code
end

def professional_user_register
  #Professonal User Register Code
end
```

Comment: I think this is what I want to do.  One question....If I wanted to display different views depending on what link the user, professional or employer, came from what would i do.  I think I would put some logic in the create saying if professional and else and display the views for sign up.  I am just not sure how to do it because they, the user, has not been defined as of yet.  They have not signed up.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: See above code. I have edited the answer. You could have different actions for different roles. Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Devise allows you to set up as many Devise models as you want.

[Configuring multiple models](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-multiple-models)

You can configure views for each model

[Configuring views](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views)